# Returning Single-Row queries using ASP.NET using DataAdapter, DataTable, and DataRow

Tags: asp.net

I'm fairly new to ASP.NET and am working through a tutorial that demonstrates the use of DataAdapter, DataTable, and DataRow classes.  The tutorial focuses on binding returned DataTables to GridView objects - I'm having trouble understanding what to do to extract one row for display.

I've found I can do the following:

```
ProductsTableAdapter productsAdapter = new ProductsTableAdapter(); 
Northwind.ProductsTable productsTable = productsAdapter.GetSingleByProductID(searchID)
Northwind.ProductsRow productRow = (Northwind.ProductsRow)productsTable.Rows[0];
```

A ProductsTable should be able to return its own ProductRows w/o resorting to a cast, no?  Can't find how to do it otherwise.

I'm thinking how to go about creating a form where the user will only ever be working on one record at a time.  Wouldn't it make sense for the DAL to return a ProductsRow instead of a ProductsTable?

Answer (score 0):

Use DataReader to return datatable.
It is fastest way to return data from database.

Comment: Not worried about speed but quick development.  Using the built in wizards to generate the data access layer classes seems faster than building my own ORMs.